# How can I merge both values using Single.flatMap?

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have this code:

```
private Single<Invoice> getInvoiceWithItems() {
    return getInvoice().flatMap(invoice -> getItems(invoice)); // <--- Here, I need invoice and items
}

private Single<Invoice> getInvoice() { ... }

private Single<List<Item>> getItems(Invoice invoice) { ... }
```

I want to do something like `invoice.setItems(items)`. I tried passing an extra function parameter to `flatMap` but it doesn't accept it.

How can I do it?

I found this solution, but I'm not sure if it is the best one:

```
private Single<Invoice> getInvoiceWithItems() {
    return Single.zip(getInvoice(), getInvoice().flatMap(invoice -> getInvoiceItems(invoice)), (invoice, items) -> {
        invoice.setItems(items);
        return invoice;
    });
}
```

Comment: what is `Invoice` like?

Comment: @VishwaRatna it's just a POJO with some properties, `items` is one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Single<Invoice> getInvoiceWithItems() {
    return getInvoice().flatMap(invoice -> getItems(invoice).map(items -> {
        invoice.setItems(items);
        return invoice;
    }));
}
```